# svn2git fails to correctly import tags

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

I have an `SVN`-repository which I would like to convert into a `git`-repository. I'm using `svn2git` to achieve this. Unfortunately it seems like the tool is having problems getting the tags right. My `SVN`-repository looks like this:

```
.../branches
.../tags
        project-version-5.2.5/
        project-version-5.3.0/
        project-version-5.3.1/
        project-version-5.4.0/
        project-version-5.5.0/
        project-version-5.5.1/
        project-version-5.5.2/
        project-version-5.5.3/
        project-version-5.5.4/
        project-version-5.6.0/
        project-version-5.6.1/
        project-version-5.6.2/
        project-version-5.6.3/
        project-version-5.6.4/
        project-version-5.6.5/
        project-version-5.6.6/
        project-version-6.0.0/
        project-version-6.0.1/
        project-version-6.0.2/
        project-version-6.1.0/
        project-version-6.1.1/
        project-version-6.1.2/
        project-version-6.2.0/
        project-version-6.2.1/
.../trunk
```

But the git repository is not representing this. The tags look like this:

```
bash:~$ git tag
project-version-5.2.5
project-version-5.3.0
project-version-5.3.1
project-version-5.3.1@3812 <-- I have no idea, where that is coming from...
project-version-5.4.0
project-version-5.5.0
project-version-5.5.1
project-version-5.5.2
project-version-5.5.3
project-version-5.5.4
project-version-5.6.0
project-version-5.6.1
project-version-5.6.2
project-version-5.6.3
project-version-5.6.4
project-version-5.6.5
```

Notice the missing tags. They are for some reason stored as remote branches:

```
bash:~$ git branch -r
  svn/tags/project-version-5.6.5@4990 <-- Yay, random numbers!
  svn/tags/project-version-5.6.6
  svn/tags/project-version-5.6.6@5620 <-- And another one. 
  svn/tags/project-version-6.0.0
  svn/tags/project-version-6.0.1
  svn/tags/project-version-6.0.2
  svn/tags/project-version-6.1.0
  svn/tags/project-version-6.1.1
  svn/tags/project-version-6.1.2
  svn/tags/project-version-6.2.0
  svn/tags/project-version-6.2.1
  svn/trunk
```

What is happening here?

Edit: I forgot to add my command: `svn2git http://path/to/repository --no-minimize-url --verbose --username='username' --trunk trunk --nobranches --tags tags`

Edit2: I just checked and found, that the seemingly random numbers are actually revisions in the `SVN`-repository, which the tags were made from. It's kind of strange, that only 3 out of ~20 tags get the revision added to them...

Edit3: Obviously the problem has something to do with the comment of one tag, which contains `"`. All tags after that one are saved as branches, because `svn2git` doesn't escape `"` and tries to do something like

```
git tag -a -m "blablabla "blablabla"." "project-version-5.6.5@4990" "svn/tags/project-version-5.6.5@4990"
```

which fails for obvious reasons. I still have no idea, why for some tags it adds the revision number though. If anyone has any suggestions how to overcome this problem, I would be very thankful.

Edit4: I found the solution for the escaping problem. The escape-function in the `svn2git`-source is just kind of weird...It only substitutes single quotes (`'`) with `'\''`. I'm done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding double-quote escaping. Since this change is already suggested on `github` I didn't start another pull-request for that. Though for the next one with the same problem, here is what I did:

1. `locate migration.rb` - In my case this was in `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/svn2git-2.2.2/lib/svn2git/migration.rb`
2. Find the definition of `escape_quotes()` (currently to be found in lines `335-337`)
3. Add `.gsub("\"", "\\\"")` to the body

I hope, this will help someone with the same problem some time :)

Comment: where is the github thread? I have the same problem but we're so many years later now. The code is bit different now and it contains `str.gsub(/'|"/) { |c| "\\#{c}" }` in the body but I don't know ruby good enough to know what I have to change. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

I found this question when I also wondered about those `@nnn` tags. So if someone else is looking for the same it's described in the [git svn manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

> If git svn is configured to fetch branches (and --follow-branches is in effect), it sometimes creates multiple Git branches for one SVN branch, where the additional branches have names of the form branchname@nnn (with nnn an SVN revision number). These additional branches are created if git svn cannot find a parent commit for the first commit in an SVN branch, to connect the branch to the history of the other branches.